# Stuck on Cordova Splash Screen with Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova

I built a new project with Cordova and installed all the new necessary plugins that my old project needed. I then ported over my `www` folder to the new one.

I'm encountering a problem when starting up the emulator where all it displays it the Cordova splash screen and not my actual project. I thought a problem would be in my config.xml file but I do not see anything out of the ordinary.

Is there an extra line of code I have to insert because my project is on Android Studio with a gradle now?

My config.xml:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to ur config.xml seems missing

`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay"            value="10000" />`
 
    `<preference name="SplashScreen"                 value="screen" />`
That wIll make it display fOr 10 seconds and then continue
.
YOU CAN CHANGE YOUR TIME TO allow  splash screen display in vaLue

Comment: Remove autohide splashscreen preference in your config.xml file